# Angular 2 templates: defining a callback

Tags: templates, angular

I'll create a simplified example of my real world problem, so let's say i have a component that lists objects.

It takes the input `@Input() objects: Object[]` and `@Input label: Function`, so that it can output markup for each of the `objects` having the return value of `label` for each of them.

The `label` should be a function creating a string and depending on the object, so that the child component is as flexible as possible in how it presents each object.
Like `id + title` or `"This is item " + number` or `"item " + title + " costs " + cost + "$"`...

A practial `label` could be `e => e.id + ': ' + e.title` where `e` (the argument for `label` is the respective item of `objects`)

Now I would like to use this component B within another component's template A without adding the `label` function to A's component class because this would clutter A's component class a lot. I'd like to define the `label` function in the template, e.g. with

```
<my-selector [objects]="myObjects" [label]="e => e.id + ': ' + e.title"
```

But no matter which notation I try, angular seems to discourage this with errors like `Bindings cannot contain assignments` and the like...

Question:
Is this possible to achieve and if not, what is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: just create a function and pass that function instead of `e => e.id + ': ' + e.title`

Comment: Why are you passing functions as an Input to child components? As shown above, `label` is function. It is encouraged to pass down values as inputs.
If by any chance you want to access a function in a child component, you can always do that using the instance of that child component.

Comment: I want to do this because the child component should be flexible in how it renders the objects. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to define a function in the template explicitly, but you can define it in the component class:

```
constructLabel(e): string {
    console.log('Constructing label...');
    return e.id + ': ' + e.title;
};
```

bind the pointer:

```
[constructLabel]="constructLabel"
```

and call it in the child component:

```
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() constructLabel: Function;

    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let e = {};
        this.constructLabel(e); // => Constructing label...
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an explanation why it has to be a function and your second solution works of course, but i stated that i do not want to clutter the component with additional functions and instead define it directly in the template. So my question refers to if this is possible without adding the function to the component class.

Comment: There is no way to define a function from within the template, also I can't see a valid reason for doing that. However, if you need to execute the function in the child component, you can define it in your parent component and bind a pointer in the template. I will update my answer demonstrating it.

Comment: So then the right answer to my question `Is this possible to achieve and if not, what is the best approach to solve this?` would be `No it is not and the best solution is writing the function in the component`. Thanks and I'll accept your answer if you update accordingly.

Comment: `[label]="constructLabel(e)"` would call the function immediadely and pass the result. `[label]="constructLabel"` passes the function to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it is currently not possible to define a function inside an Angular 2 template. So you have to define the function in the component

```
constructLabel(e): string {
  return e.id + ': ' + e.title;
};
```

and pass it via

```
[label]="constructLabel"
```